# Compare 2 List<int> and find 5 int numbers in a row C#

Tags: c#

I got 2 int List like below

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int> { 2, 6, 1, 8, 9, 4, 12, 24, 23, 3, 11, 15 }; 

List<int> list2 = new List<int> { 6, 9, 4, 12, 24, 23, 5, 16, 18, 2, 7, 14 };
```

list1 = { 2, 6, 1, 8, **9, 4, 12, 24, 23,** 3, 11, 15 };

list2 = { 6, **9, 4, 12, 24, 23,** 5, 16, 18, 2, 7, 14, };

When I compare this 2 lists i need to get result in new List like:

{ **9, 4, 12, 24, 23** }

Need fast working solution under 500 ms. Original list contains 35 int items and need to find 5 same like on example above.

Comment: What did you tried so far ?

Comment: How many milliseconds do you wanna work it exactly?

Comment: 500ms for this? Gosh, you're gonna need some kind of *supercomputer*

Comment: max what I can span on this comparation is 500ms, more from that is not acceptably

Comment: So here's the most braindead solution I can think of. Loop through every length-5 subsets of list one. For each one, loop though every length-5 subset of list 2. When they match, you're done.

Comment: *500 ms* is *1/2* second, since 1 *millisecond* (ms) is 1/1000 second? And the solution could be as slow as sloth?

Comment: This is similar to a well-known sub-string search algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a dumb solution that executes for me in less than 0.000 seconds on my machine, and 0.016 seconds on [.dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4pHUIP).

```
public static void Main()
{
    List<int> list1 = new List<int> { 2, 6, 1, 8, 9, 4, 12, 24, 23, 3, 11, 15 };        
    List<int> list2 = new List<int> { 6, 9, 4, 12, 24, 23, 5, 16, 18, 2, 7, 14 };

    CommonSublist(5, list1, list2).Dump();
}

private static List<int> CommonSublist(int length, List<int> list1, List<int> list2) {
    for (int i=0;i<list1.Count-length;i++) {
        for (int j=0;j<list2.Count-length;j++) {
            List<int> output = new List<int>();
            for (int k=0;k<length;k++) {
                if (list1[i+k]==list2[j+k]) {
                    output.Add(list1[i+k]);
                }
                else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (output.Count == length) {
                return output;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Seriously, I answered pretty much the same solution just six minutes ago. However, you don't need the innermost list, this is just a waste of memory. You can just take a boolean to remember if all of the sublist items match.

Comment: Congratulations? And I said it was a dumb solution. Yours requires a very hard coded substring length, mine does not.  All for the cost of 5 ints of memory.

Comment: Of course you can introduce a variable for the sublist length but either way you should not create a list in the innermost loop, I will edit the post to show you what i mean.

Comment: It doesn't matter. My point was that the most obvious, non optimised solution executes in basically zero time with basically zero memory.

Comment: Honestly I would be impressed if you *could* write something that ran longer than 500ms without thread.Sleep or empty busy loops

Comment: @Blorgbeard It is not just 5 ints of memory, it is O(n²) list allocations that will consume about 40 bytes each. Still, for n=200 this is just about 1.6Mb which is "nothing" for current machines. It is also up to 40.000 objects that will pollute the GC. I think this is a wate given that there is a solution that really does not need a singe object allocation. But of course, your solution solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best what you can do is go through the list and see whether you find a good starting index.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= list1.Count - length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= list2.Count - length; j++)
    {
        var match = true;
        for (int k = 0; k < length; k++)
        {
            if (list1[k] != list2[k]) { match = false; break; }
        }
        if (match)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting indices are {0} and {1}", i,j);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit2:** Introduced variable length sublists

**Edit:** Maybe you can accelerate this solution by prefiltering the indices as you create sums of the 5-element-chunks and intersect these sums. This will need O(n) for creating the sums and O(n) for intersecting them. However, then it is up to your data distribution whether you can find the true substrings in less than O(n^2) but you might be lucky.

Alternatively, you can save the concatenation of the strings separated by e.g. a semicolon and then intersect the strings. This will run deterministal in O(n) but will have a high memory footprint.